# Attaching methods to prototype from within constructor function

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Here is the textbook standard way of describing a 'class' or constructor function in JavaScript, straight from the *Definitive Guide to JavaScript*:

```
function Rectangle(w,h) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
}
Rectangle.prototype.area = function() { 
    return this.width * this.height;
};
```

I don't like the dangling prototype manipulation here, so I was trying to think of a way to encapsulate the function definition for `area` inside the constructor. I came up with this, which I did **not** expect to work:

```
function Rectangle(w,h) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.constructor.prototype.area = function() { 
        return this.width * this.height;
    };
}
```

I didn't expect this to work because the `this` reference inside the `area` function should be pointing to the `area` function itself, so I wouldn't have access to `width` and `height` from `this`. But it turns out I do!

```
var rect = new Rectangle(2,3);
var area = rect.area(); // great scott! it is 6
```

Some further testing confirmed that the `this` reference inside the `area` function actually was a reference to the *object under construction*, not the area function itself.

```
function Rectangle(w,h) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    var me = this;
    this.constructor.prototype.whatever = function() { 
        if (this === me) { alert ('this is not what you think');}
    };
}
```

Turns out the alert pops up, and `this` is exactly the **object under construction**. So what is going on here? Why is `this` not the `this` I expect it to be?

Comment: If you have a hundred rectangles, you are going to redeclare that prototype method a hundred times. 
Good thing you only have one method...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the right answer is that you should not do this because as kennebec said in the comment:

> If you have a hundred rectangles, you
>   are going to redeclare that prototype
>   method a hundred times.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that 'this' always referred to the object against which the function was called.

Comment: I think the official answer is "it depends".

Comment: To clarify, `this` referes to the object through which the function was invoked when the function is used as a method on an object. This is not the case here. In this case, the function is being invoked as a function and not a method on an object, so `this` really should refer to the global object.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `this` depends how the function was called:

- `this` usually refers to the object the function is called from at runtime, e.g. when called as `ob.foo()`, `this` in foo will refer to ob.
- If a function is called in a no-object-provided way, e.g. just `foo()`, `this` refers to the global variable (the top object that contains all other global variables in your js program).
- And in `.call()` and `.apply()`, the object that `this` refers to is supplied.

Now, if you wanted a way to point to the object for the function that your function was created in (i.e., the 2nd level `this` at the time of creation), then you would have to rename the deeper `this` to make it shine through the currently-visible one. If that's clear as mud, this should help clarify a bit:

```
function outside() {
    // Here, 'this' refers to the object outside() is called with.
    // Let's "rename" this, to make it visible to inside functions.
    var that = this,
        private = 42;

    return {
        inside: function {
            // here, 'this' refers to the object inside() is called with,
            //  it is hiding outside's this.
            // Also, 'that' refers to the object outside() was called with,
            //  *at the time* outside was called and inside was created.
            // Notice that you can see 'private'
            // (but nobody outside of 'outside()) can!
            return private;
        }
    }
}
```

This pattern above is useful to create object with public methods that can access private members. See [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) for probably better explanations.

Answer (score 0):

What 'this' points to, is determined when the code is run.

Here's an easy way to figure out what 'this' should be.

If you use '.' to reference a function, 'this' will be a reference to whatever is on the left side of the '.'

(This doesn't account for .call and .apply)

```
var myFn = function () {
return this.name + ' called me';
};

var me = {
name : 'oatkiller',
shoutOut : myFn
};

var you = {
name : 'Matthew',
shoutOut : myFn
};

// im on the left of the dot, so this points to me
me.shoutOut(); // 'oatkiller called me'

// youre on the left of the dot, so this points to you
you.shoutOut(); // 'Matthew called me'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're really close with the final example. How about using a privileged method:

```
function Rectangle(w,h) {
  this.width = w;
  this.height = h;
  var that = this;
  this.area = function() { 
    return that.width * that.height;
  }
}

var rect = new Rectangle(2,3);
console.log(rect.area());
```

See [Crockford's "Private Members in JavaScript"](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) for more info.